# Can I programmatically like list items in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/03/01/liking-and-rating-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Can I set user likes in list items from C# code? It will be very useful for me to provide likes for some of list items, not from site contents settings.

Comment: http://www.sharepointcolumn.com/reputation-class-in-sharepoint-2013/

Reputation class of Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll has methods for set likes or set ratings. Not tested this yet but hope it will be work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to like/unlike an item programmatically.

1. Using the [Reputation class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.reputationmodel.reputation.aspx). This is the recommended way.

   To like an item:

   ```
   Reputation.SetLike(listID, itemID, true);
   ```

   To unlike an item:

   ```
   Reputation.SetLike(listID, itemID, false);
   ```
2. Directly by updating the item's LikesCount and LikedBy fields.

   SPFieldUserValueCollection likedBy = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(web, doc["LikedBy"].ToString());

   ```
   SPUser user = web.EnsureUser("YOURDOMAIN\\USERNAME");
   SPFieldUserValue newUser = new SPFieldUserValue(web, user.ID, user.Name);

   likedBy.Add(newUser);
   int likes = likedBy.Distinct().Count();
   doc["LikesCount"] = likes;
   doc["LikedBy"] = likedBy;
   doc.SystemUpdate(false);
   ```

If you increase LikesCount without adding new user in LikedBy field the item will show the increased number of likes temporarily but with the first like/unlike from a user using the UI the number of likes will be automatically corrected to reflect the number of users that have liked the item.

To unlike a list item decrease LikeCount field value and remove the user from LikedBy.

Comment: already find first solution but thanks a lot for second case. Can you advise me how i can check is list item liked by current user?

Comment: you can check is the current user in the LikedBy field or not.

Comment: yep. Checking of LikedBy collection is the only way. Thanks for advise.